# Converting a single Tenant Application to a multitenant one using Apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant

I've built a single tenant rails application with all core features ready to ship. But I now want to make it multi-tenant using the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). Most tutorials I've found all show how to start from scratch. But I find no pointers on how to convert an existing project to have multi-tenancy built in. From my research I found that all models need a tenant ID added in the migration. How do I add this to all existing models easily? Does installing the gem and running the generator suffice? I'm running a `rails 5` API application with close to 30 models and using `graphql` ruby in an `Ubuntu 18.04` environment.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @lacostenycoder for pointing me in the right direction. Here's what I did.

**Short answer**: Yes, installing the gem, running the generator and creating your tenant model should suffice. Apartment reads your schema and creates schemas for the tenants.

**Long answer**, my experience:

1. I Backed up existing data from my database just in-case.
2. Installed apartment gem
3. If you are using any PostgreSQL database extensions like I was  (pgcrypto, uuid-    ssop)you need to understand that the extensions are not automatically loaded into the newly created schema.([look here for more details](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/342#issuecomment-235914359)) do the following:

   - Follow instructions the [github readme](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#1-ensure-the-extensions-schema-is-created-when-the-database-is-created) to create a `shared_extensions` schema
   - Create your first tenant. If it works, all is well. But...
   - If that doesn’t work, I mean when you create a tenant you get errors like  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function gen_random_uuid() does not exist`
   - or  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist` (more details [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/86), [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/342) and [here](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/521)) like it was my case when creating my first tenant, I discovered that once the extensions are enabled on the `public` schema, they cannot be installed in the shared schema `shared_extensions` in this case. So you have to change them from the public schema to the `shared_extensions` schema. get more details [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/86#issuecomment-110128354)
   - If you are using **uuid-ossp** `ALTER EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" SET SCHEMA shared_extensions` in your `rails dbconsole`
   - If you are using **pgcrypto** `ALTER EXTENSION "pgcrypto" SET SCHEMA shared_extensions` in your `rails dbconsole`

The apartment gem will create all models for your tenant once you have it set up correctly and create your first tenant.

For more information on check out some of these github issues on apartment. [Here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/86) and [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/342).
Took me a day to figure it out and gather that info. I hope it saves you time and headache!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any reason why you can't add this to an existing Rails app. I have not done this myself, nor does there appear to be any specific tutorials on how to migrate an existing app.  Follow the gem setup instructions as shown on the [README](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) and also [see the wiki](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/wiki) for additional configurations and instructions.  Use TDD wherever possible and expect to make changes to your application to get everything working correctly. Depending on how complex your existing app is will determine how much work this move will be.

You'll likely want to use `lvh.me:3000` instead of `localhost:3000` as root domain and port in your browser and perhaps use `rails s -b lvh.me` when starting your local server.

If you want to safely hack through this branch I recommend that you make a full backup of your local development database before you get started so that you can rollback to your stable current version in the event things go horribly wrong. If you're using Postgres for example there's [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgrestore.html)

This approach combined with good TDD should get you where you need to be.